# How to rewrite all url's to index.php with .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

In an application I want all users to start at index.php. So I want to redirect all direct URLs to other pages to this file.

When I use the following syntax, only the non-existing files are rewritten, but I want to redirect the existing URLs too.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Remove the `RewriteCond` ?

Answer (score 3):

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` means: if this *file* does not exist, apply the RewriteRule.

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` means: if this *directory* does not exist, apply the RewriteRule.

Use:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

---

**EDIT:**

If you want to redirect only when the URL does not start with `/index.php` yet, use this extra condition:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thank you. This works fine but  is it possible to let it work once? so as the entry is index.php than all other url's via de menu will work. I just want all users to force a start at index.php.